# why my style sheets are loaded for all other pages except one page, i get 404 for stylesheet files on that page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I hope you all are doing great, I ran into this wild issue, I'm making my front end in react, and I have several pages in my app, css for all the pages is defined in only one file and I'm loading it from the main HTML document(not react components). CSS for all the pages is loaded but not for one particular page, the link of that page is sent via email through sendgrid, when I browse the page I get 404 for stylesheet and bootstrap files.

This is how I'm loading style sheet from HTML document which hosts the root component of reacting.

```
<html>
  <head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/assets/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="app-root"></div>

     <script src="/app/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

following are the screenshots of the network statistics for the pages which are loaded with css. [image: page loaded with css]

page failed to load with CSS with the same link to CSS files as the that of the prior one.

[image: page failed to load with css]

what seems to be the problem here, thank you, everybody, for taking out time and reading out this.

Comment: Are the css urls in the first and second screenshot the same?

Comment: Could be a lot of things. I don't know if you use gulp, webpack, grunt, or something else in the first place. If I was doing this I'd probably install https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader via npm , configure it with webpack, and use the app.js to load the CSS modules altogether, since it loads only the necessary stuff.

Comment: Your using relative urls.  Try placing a slash at start e.g..  '/app/....'

Comment: Put a leading `/` in front of href to make it absolute

Comment: @keith yes man you are the savior, thankyou very much it did the trick

Comment: @h77 dude you're right, configuring with webpack saves from housekeeping ,but this isn't my code i have been given it to refactor the crap out of it thankyou for responding :)

Comment: @charlietfl  thankyou very much dude..

Comment: most probably it is path issue. Please share the file path for both the scenario

Comment: @keith could you please explain me in easy words what relative path and absouloute paths are, i read about it number of times but couldn't grab the concept.

Comment: It just means if say your current path was `/xyz` and you asked for `abc` without the `/` at the start it appends to the current path giving you `/xyz/abc`.  With absolute paths it ignores the current path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/assets/css/style.css">
```